# Полный экран Cefsharp WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно есть условный код:

```
namespace FullsreenCefSharp
{      
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
            Browse_my.DisplayHandler = new DisplayHandler_my();            
        }
    }

    class DisplayHandler_my : IDisplayHandler
    {
        public void OnAddressChanged(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, AddressChangedEventArgs addressChangedArgs)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool OnAutoResize(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefSharp.Structs.Size newSize)
        {
            return true;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool OnConsoleMessage(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, ConsoleMessageEventArgs consoleMessageArgs)
        {
            return true;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnFaviconUrlChange(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IList<string> urls)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnLoadingProgressChange(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, double progress)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnStatusMessage(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, StatusMessageEventArgs statusMessageArgs)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnTitleChanged(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, TitleChangedEventArgs titleChangedArgs)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool OnTooltipChanged(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, ref string text)
        {
            return true;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        void IDisplayHandler.OnFullscreenModeChange(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, bool fullscreen)
        {
            if (fullscreen)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс, DisplayHandler_my, реализует интерфейс...и при нажатии кнопки (например на ютубе) переключения в полный экран, срабатывает метод OnFullscreenModeChange.. Но как я только не пробовал.

Если обращаться к классу MainWindow к условному методу

```
public void full()
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None
}
```

То ругается на поток, а если вызвать в основном потоке через Dispatcher..то программа закрывается с исключением.

В общем, как правильно запустить полный экран из метода OnFullscreenModeChange

Comment: через Dispather тоже по-разному можно пробовать, покажите как пробовали

Comment: Может попробовать как здесь: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/7f1f1c5f214e10c77f3c47740e8ef9ac26830be9#diff-c2d72c89ae2f1668e2302d726a1b58aeR32

Имею ввиду: `chromiumWebBrowser.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired`

Comment: @CasperSC вот так как здесь, работает только на WindowsForm, а мне WPF

Comment: Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                           //код для UI
                        });